# Integration bounds for convolution

Tags: probability, convolution

> Given a joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)$ on triangle with vertex $(5,0),(5,1),(4,1)$ I can't understand how to find integration bounds for convolution of $Z=X+Y$. I know that the solution should be
>   $$F_z(z)=\int_{z-1}^{5}\left(\int_{z-x}^{1}f_{XY}(x,y)dy\right)dx$$

Any suggestion? :-)

**Edit**

Based on JeanMarie's answer is correct that if I change the vertex to $(1,0),(1,1),(2,1)$ then $$F_z(z)=\int_{1}^{z/2}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f_{XY}(x,y)dy\right)dx + \int_{z/2}^{2}\left(\int_{x}^{1}f_{XY}(x,y)dy\right)dx$$?

Comment: Draw triangle ABC. Consider lines with common equation $x+y=k$. For $k$ between $5$ and $6$, they divide the triangle into a trapezoid and a triangle. Integrate on the trapezoid.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ok, I drawn what you suggest but I can't visualize bounds.

Comment: Do you agree that when $k$ increases the line $L_z$ with equation $x+y=z$ sweeps across the triangle ? The cumulative distribution function (cdf) F of $Z=X+Y$ is, by definition of a cdf, the probability associated with the trapezoid defined by $P(Z<z)$. For example, if $z=5.5$ and the distribution is uniform, you will get $P(Z<5.5)=3/4$. It is simpler to consider the probability $p$ of being in the triangle and take $1-p$. Then how do you compute it ? For a given value of $z$, by taking $y$ from $y=z-x$ (so that $x+y=z$) to $y=1$ and take $x$ from $x=z-1$ to $x=5$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I've read your answer, it's totally clear. If I change the vertex to $(1,0),(1,1),(2,1)$ is correct that $F_z(z)=\int_{1}^{z/2}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f_{XY}(x,y)dy\right)dx + \int_{z/2}^{2}\left(\int_{x}^{1}f_{XY}(x,y)dy\right)dx$?

Comment: I would not call that a convolution (BTW, the property: "the density (not the distribution) of a sum of independent variables is the convolution of the marginal densities" applies only to independent variables).